# DELL Inspirion 15, Fan stop after hard drive replace

Tags: hard-drive, fan, dell-inspiron

Few days ago I changed hard drive in mom laptop (old about 8-9 years), but when I put new drive, cpu fan stopped. I check 2 other WD and Seagate. It's not helpful, but when I return to old HDD everything works correct, why? Nothing is broken, because it's work with old setup.

BIOS diagnostic nothing found.

Comment: Other than the fan not running, does the laptop work correctly?

Comment: Yes, everything works correct w/o fan, CPU was very hot, after restart we had cpu thermal throttling error

Comment: my guess is that the temperature sensor for the hdd is either not working or not present. This might then lead the machine not to spi n the fans up as early. leave the machine running for a while and see what happens.